# NSUserDefaults giving error

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsuserdefaults

I am using NSUserDefaults in my application. It was working fine until i was having ios 4.3 and xcode 4.0. But now i have updated to ios 5 and xcode 4.2...

It's giving error!

```
NSString *storedLanguage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"language"];


*** -[NSUserDefaults objectForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x26e800
```

I don't know how to resolve it..i have tried all my effort!

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: try to separate the initiation and method invoke statement. Like NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; then NSString * storedLanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"language"];

Comment: i have done it But then  NSString * storedLanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"language"]; giving same error

Comment: Can you post the entire code for your function? Did you do anything to the NSUserDefaults object by any chance?

Comment: Iterate UserDefaults. Check if the key you're looking for ("language") exists or what type of data does it contain?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: No problem is not solved!!@Gomathi

Comment: I am surprised! It's working in one class....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from your question its looking like early release of some object.
Cant say where is the problem.
But give a try to this one

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain];
NSString * storedLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"language"]];
[defaults release];
```

=============================== OR ================================
This one

```
NSString *sessionId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"language"]];
```

They might help you...

Cheers

Comment: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain]; now giving the error...                     *** -[NSUserDefaults retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: Have you tried the second part which i have written,use with NSString specifier,then check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Please do the same thing said by Naved but with little modification.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain];
NSString * storedLanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"language"];
[defaults release];
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain]; now giving the error...                     *** -[NSUserDefaults retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Answer (score 0):

Use a different key for your settings that doesn't collide with reserved (existing but inaccessible) setting names. (e.g. "MyUsersLanguageSettingsKey")

Comment: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain]; giving the error...          it's not the error of key.. it is giving error on object of nsuserdefaults..

Comment: which error exactly? debug output? (you can also set a workspace breakpoint on "objc_exception_throw" (xcode: exception breakpoint on throw) and "abort" (xcode: symbolic breakpoint))

Comment: I am using nsuserdefaults in my appdelegate file. IT's working fine here..But there is problem with other classes which loads after the appDelegate file..

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine now.. Actually there is one thing in ios5. If you release your nsdefaults in one class, you can't use anywhere in the application..

I was releasing the NSDefaults in my appdelegate file. so it was not working in other classes..But it was working in ios4..  I don't know why it was working here?

Thanks to all for giving time!!